# Read the objects using EntityFramework6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, linq-to-objects

i want to read all the object that i have in my database and return them using a web api controller.

There is a 3 level of tables.  Template has a list of Paragraphs and a Paragraph has a list of DataValues.

Reading the templates and the Paragraph is easy i just do:

```
Database db = new Database();
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
var aux = db.Templates.Include("Paragraphs");
```

if i add also the DataVlues like this

```
var aux = db.Templates.Include("Paragraphs").Include("DataValues");
```

I get this message:

```
A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'Database.Template' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'DataValues'.
```

I know that this error is normal, but how to also read DataValues in this way?

I have to create a POCO object of this values from EF([POCO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_CLR_Object))

Comment: any ideas if Join() would help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because DataValues is a navigation proprty for Paragraphs and you only can access from Paragraphs,  so for Template,  it is not a first level property,   so change your code to be :

```
var aux = db.Templates
.Include("Paragraphs")
.Include("Paragraphs.DataValues");
```

Comment: this one works as i wanted

Answer (score 0):

Navigation property should be of entity type of collection of related entities. Including some navigation property means joining your current entity with some related entity or entities. That allows eager loading of data from several tables in single query. `DataValues` is not a navigation property - it is field, and it will be loaded by default, you don't need to include it:

note:

> complex types shouldn't contain navigation properties (as well as
>   foreign keys)

Comment: DataValue* is a table in my model